# If $S=\{z\in\mathbb C:z\neq0\text{ and }\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|=a\}$ find $\min\limits_{z\in S}|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $a$ is a positive real number and $S=\{z\in \mathbb C : z\neq 0\ \text{ and } \vert z+\frac{1}{z}\vert = a\}$, Find $\min\limits_{z\in S}\vert z\vert$ and $\min\limits_{z\in S}\vert\frac{1}{z}\vert$

I first tried using the triangle inequality to get:
$$\vert z\vert^2-a\vert z\vert+1\ge 0$$
$$\vert z\vert\in\big(-\infty,\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}\big)\cup\big(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2},\infty\big)$$
since $\vert z\vert\ge 0$ and $a^2>a^2-4$,
$$\vert z\vert\in\big(0,\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}\big)\cup\big(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2},\infty\big)$$

So $\min\vert z \vert=0$. But the answer given is $\min\vert z\vert=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4}-a}{2}$

Comment: What else do we know about $a$?

Comment: Its a positive real number

Comment: Right, I got that; but Don't we need $|a|\geq 2$ so that the answer makes sense?

Comment: Yes. We need |a|>=2 since |z|>=0

Comment: @AdityaDev Note that you're argument is not valid if $-2<a<2$. Also note that finding an inequality is not enough to say that you found a minimum; you need to show that in fact there is some $z$ for which $|z|$ gets minimum. Otherwise, you've only found a lower bound.

Comment: The minimum of $|z|$ cannot be $\frac{-|a|+\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}<0$ for $|a|>2$ since $|z|\ge 0$.

Comment: The "answer given" is negative. You may want to double check the result.

Comment: See:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997308/if-z-frac1z-a-find-extreme-values-of-z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\phi}$.$\,\,\,$  If $|z+z^{-1}|=a$, then

$$r^2+r^{-2}+2\cos(2\phi)=a^2 \tag 1$$

We can write $(1)$ in a more convenient form as

$$\left(r+\frac1r\right)^2=a^2-4\sin^2(\phi) \tag 2$$

Note that $|a|\ge 2$ since the minimum of $r+\frac1r$ is $2$.

Now, differentiating both sides of $(2)$ with respect to $\phi$ yields

$$\left(2r-\frac{2}{r^3}\right)\frac{dr}{d\phi}=-4\sin(2\phi)$$

whereupon setting $\frac{dr}{d\phi}$ to $0$ reveals that $2\phi = \ell \pi$ for integer $\ell$.

For $r\le 1$, the minimum for $r$ occurs when $2\phi =0$.  Substituting $2\phi=0$ into $(2)$ reveals

$$r_{min}+\frac1{r_{min}}=|a| \implies r_{min}=\frac{|a|-\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}$$

Comment: Why didnt you differentiate with respect to $r$?

Comment: The differentiation is with respect to $\phi$.  I stated this explicitly and even wrote $dr/d\phi$.

Comment: what happens if you differentiate with respect to r?

Comment: $r$ is considered a function of $\phi$.  Analogously, how does one find a local minimum of a function $f(x)$?  Find the values of $x$ where $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy,\ \bar z = x-iy$.

If $\left|z+\frac 1 z \right| = a$, then

$$z+\frac 1 z = a e^{it}$$ for some $t$.

This transforms into

$$z^2 - ae^{it}z+1=0.$$
Similarilry, we can get

$${\bar z}^2 - ae^{-it}\bar z+1=0.$$

Subtract these two equations; we get

$$z^2 -{\bar z}^2 -a(e^{it}z - e^{-it}\bar z)=0.$$

This is equivalent to

$$4ixy -2a\Im({e^{it}z})=4ixy-2a(x\sin t +y\cos t)=0.$$

For this equality to hold, we have one of two options:

1. $x=0$, which implies that $t = \pi / 2$ since we don't want $y=0$,
2. $y=0$, which implies that $t = 0 $ since we don't want $x=0$.

In the first case,

$$\left| iy+\frac {1}{iy}\right| = a$$

implies that

$$y=\pm \frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}.$$ Since $a$ is positive, the minimum occurs at

$$y=\pm \frac{a- \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}.$$

Therefore the minimum is

$$ \frac{a- \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}$$

Do a similar method for case $2$.

Hint for the second part: the minimum of $|1/z|$ is achieved at the maximum of $|z|$.