# To find minimum and maximum value of $|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ be a complex number such that $\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|=a$,then prove that $\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4}-a}{2}\leq |z|\leq\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4}+a}{2}$.

My attempt:$\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|\leq |z|+\frac{1}{|z|}$ i.e.$a\leq |z|+\frac{1}{|z|}$ gives $|z|^2-a|z|+1\geq0$ which gives $|z|\in\left(0,\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4}-a}{2}\right]\bigcup\left[\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4}+a}{2},\infty\right)$.

However,$\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|= |z-\frac{1}{-z}|\geq\left||z|-|\frac{1}{-z}|\right|$, i.e.$a\geq\left||z|-\frac{1}{|z|}\right|$ yields $-a\leq|z|-\frac{1}{|z|}\leq a$ which gives the right answer.

I am probably missing out something on triangle inequality and its geometrical interpretation in case of equality

Comment: I found one answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997308/if-z-frac1z-a-find-extreme-values-of-z?rq=1