# Greatest and least value of $\left|z\right|$ when $\left|z + \frac{1}{z}\right|=a$, $a > 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Problem.**<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyDux.jpg)</sup> If $z$ is a complex number and $\left|z + \frac{1}{z}\right|=a$, $a > 2$, then the greatest and least value of $\left|z\right|$ are respectively :

This question is from RPSC school lecture exam 2013.

I know that $\left|z + \frac{1}{z}\right| \geq |z| - \frac{1}{|z|}$. And then $|z|-\frac{1}{|z|} \leq \alpha$. I used it but I am stuck. I also don't know where to use $\alpha > 2$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful to format your title and question appropriately. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. It greatly helps the question visible to various search engines and hence is crucial for maintaining this community as a repository of mathematical knowledge. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). You may also want to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: [If $|z +\frac{1}{z}|=a$ find extreme values ​​of $|z|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997308/if-z-frac1z-a-find-extreme-values-of-z) is the same question, with the answer contained in the question itself. There is an actual answer for good measure as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parametrize $z = re^{i\theta}$. Then by using the well-known identity $|a+b|^2 = |a|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}(a\overline{b}) + |b|^2$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, we get

$$ a^2 = \left|z + \frac{1}{z}\right|^2 = |z|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z}{\overline{z}}\right) + \frac{1}{|z|^2}
= r^2 + 2\cos(2\theta) + \frac{1}{r^2}. \tag{1} $$

Manipulating this equation,

\begin{align*}
\text{(1)} &\quad\iff\quad \left(r + \frac{1}{r}\right)^2 = a^2 + 2 - 2\cos(2\theta) \\
&\quad\iff\quad r + \frac{1}{r} = \sqrt{a^2 + 2 - 2\cos(2\theta)}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Maximum.** To find the maximum $r_{\text{max}}$ of $r$, note that $z$ solves $\text{(1)}$ if and only if $\frac{1}{z}$ does. So, we may assume $r \geq 1$. Then by noting that $r \mapsto r + \frac{1}{r}$ is increasing for $r \geq 1$, the maximum of $r$ is achieved if the right-hand side of $\text{(2)}$ is maximized. Therefore $r_{\text{max}}$ satisfies

$$ r_{\text{max}} + \frac{1}{r_{\text{max}}} = \sqrt{a^2 + 4} $$

Solving this for $r_{\text{max}}$ (and choosing the solution that is $\geq 1$, of course), we get

$$ r_{\text{max}} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 4} + a}{2}. $$

**Minimum.** As we observed above, $z$ is a solution of $\text{(1)}$ if and only if $\frac{1}{z}$ is. This means that the minimum $r_{\min}$ of $r$ can be computed as

$$ r_{\min} = \frac{1}{r_{\max}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2 + 4} + a} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 4} - a}{2}. $$

**Figure.** The picture below illustrates the curve defined by the equation $\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|=3$ (blue ones) as well as the circles of radii $r_{\min}$ and $r_{\max}$ centered at zero (red ones):

[image: figure]

**Addendum.** Although the condition $a > 2$ is not crucial for the solution above, this condition *does* affect the shape of the curve(s) defined by the equation $\text{(1)}$. Indeed, $\text{(2)}$ shows that if $a < 2$, then $r$ may not exists for some $\theta$. This is also evident from the animation below, where $a$ varies from $3$ to $0.05$:

[image: animation]